# Stopwatch JavaScript with lap times (like iPhone Stopwatch)

Tags: javascript, stopwatch

I have programmed a simple stopwatch in JavaScript. However, I am not able to implement a function that returns lap times.

My goal is to program a stopwatch that works like the stopwatch in an iPhone. I need to measure the cumulative time and the single lap times (not only split times).

Maybe, has anyone already programmed a stopwatch like that?

Many thanks,

```js
//TIMER

function timeToString(time) {
  document.getElementById("time").value = time;
  return time;
}


let startTime;
let start_date;
let elapsedTime = 0;
let timerInterval;


//FUNCTION TO CHANGE INNER HTML
function print(txt) {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = txt;
}


//CREATE START PAUSE FUNCTION
function start() {
  startTime = performance.now() - elapsedTime;
  start_date = performance.now()
  timerInterval = setInterval(function printTime() {
    elapsedTime = performance.now() - startTime;
    print(timeToString(elapsedTime));
  }, 10);
  showButton("PAUSE");
}

function pause() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  showButton("PLAY");

}


//FUNCTION TO DISPLAY BUTTONS
function showButton(buttonKey) {
  const buttonToShow = buttonKey === "PLAY" ? openButton : closeButton;
  const buttonToHide = buttonKey === "PLAY" ? closeButton : openButton;
  buttonToShow.style.display = "block";
  buttonToHide.style.display = "none";
}

//EVENT LISTENER
let openButton = document.getElementById("openButton");
let closeButton = document.getElementById("closeButton");

openButton.addEventListener("click", start);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", pause);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="search_button" data-id="search_decision">
                        <span id="openButton">Start</span>
                        <span id="closeButton">Stop</span>
                    </button>


<p id="display">0</p>

<input type="hidden" name="time" id="time" value="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you want observer or not please add more details

```
class Stopwatch{
   constructor(){
    this.time = 0
    this.laps = []
    this.observers = []
   }

   stop(){
    clearInterval(this.timerInterval) 
   }

   start(){
    this.timerInterval = setInterval(() => this.time++,1000)
   }


   lap(){
    this.laps.push(this.time)
   }


  getTimeForLab(index){
    return this.laps[index] - (this.laps[index - 1] || 0)
  }


}


const stopwatch = new Stopwatch()
stopwatch.start()

stopwatch.stop()
```